# Partition table for a 4TB hard disk when cloning a hard disk with a msdos table

Tags: hard-disk, dd, partition-table, cloning

Using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I replaced the bootable internal hard disk in a desktop computer with a brand-new 2TB hard disk. I could transfer the partition table and all data from the previous hard disk using the `dd` command. The previous hard disk had a **msdos partition table**, which has been reproduced in the new hard disk automagically. Now the computer loads the OS and all that follows seamlessly.

My current plan is to replace the **hard disk in a computer with a legacy boot** with a 4TB hard disk.

Reading the `man fdisk` pages I noted two passages (in boldface):

> DISK LABELS
>
> GPT (GUID Partition Table)
> GPT  is  modern  standard  for the layout of the partition table.  GPT uses 64-bit logical block addresses, checksums, UUIDs and
> names for partitions and an unlimited number of partitions (although the number of partitions is usually restricted  to  128  in
> many partitioning tools).
>
> Note  that  the first sector is still reserved for a protective MBR in the GPT specification.  It prevents MBR-only partitioning
> tools from mis-recognizing and overwriting GPT disks.
>
> **GPT is always a better choice than MBR, especially on modern hardware with a UEFI boot loader.**
>
> DOS-type (MBR)
> A DOS-type partition table can describe an unlimited number of partitions.  In sector 0 there is room for the description  of  4
> partitions  (called  `primary').   One of these may be an extended partition; this is a box holding logical partitions, with de‐
> scriptors found in a linked list of sectors, each preceding the corresponding logical partitions.  The four primary  partitions,
> present or not, get numbers 1-4.  Logical partitions are numbered starting from 5.
>
> In a DOS-type partition table the starting offset and the size of each partition is stored in two ways: as an absolute number of
> sectors (given in 32 bits), and as a Cylinders/Heads/Sectors triple (given in 10+8+6 bits).  **The former is OK --  with  512-byte
> sectors  this  will work up to 2 TB.**  The latter has two problems.  First, these C/H/S fields can be filled only when the number
> of heads and the number of sectors per track are known.  And second, even if we know what these numbers should be, the  24  bits
> that  are  available  do  not suffice.  DOS uses C/H/S only, Windows uses both, Linux never uses C/H/S.  The C/H/S addressing is
> deprecated and may be unsupported in some later fdisk version.
> ...

Two questions arise:

- Do these suggestions imply that I **must** use a GPT partition table when I format the target 4TB hard drive, regardless of the UEFI/legacy boot mode?
- If so, can I still use `dd` to clone the **source hard drive with a msdos table** into the **target hard drive with a GPT table**?

Comment: Did you consider using a [relatively] small and fast drive for the root file system and another big drive either for a home partition or for a data partition (without any system files or configuration files but mounted automatically via `/etc/fstab`? For several years I have been using a system with a data partition, and I think it works well. - If you choose this solution, there will be no problem for you to clone the system drive. Otherwise I think you should consider a fresh installation (of the newest available Ubuntu LTS system) to a drive with GPT and also get rid of a lof of old cruft.

Comment: @sudodus Thanks for your remark. I did not and it is a good idea. Yet, the computer in point is a small-form case, so there is no space to fit a second hard drive in the case. Your suggestion opens up a new avenue though, which I am happy to consider in parallel to that sketched in the post.

Comment: What about [this link](https://www.startech.com/en-se/hdd/bracket25x2) to an adapter for two SSDs into one 3.5 inch HDD space? There are probably many similar adapters on the market.

Comment: @sudodus Another valuable suggestion of yours, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome and good luck with your upgrade of the drive :-)

Comment: I started booting Ubuntu from gpt drives in 2010. Its just you must have a bios_grub partition. It is 1 or 2MB unformatted with bios_grub flag. When UEFI came along, I made all new or repartitioned drives with both bios_grub & ESP - efi system partition (FAT32) even though I did not yet have UEFI. Only difference is version of grub, so you can easily convert from BIOS to UEFI with gpt & correct partitions, just be reinstalling correct version of grub. You cannot use dd to go from MBR to gpt, better to use rsync for data or copy data into new install.